# SQL Server - Verificar dados duplicados em dois campos simultâneos

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-select

SGBD: SQL Server 2014;

Problema: Preciso saber quais registros estão duplicados, de forma que, seja feita a verificação em dois campos simultâneos, ou seja, se o campo "CPF" com o valor '83971465842' e o campo "MAT" com o valor '001' existe, de forma idêntica, em outra tupla. Como mostra no exemplo abaixo:

```
CPF           MAT
83971465842   001
83971465842   001
57650942287   111
57655707200   305
57656959220   916
57656959220   209
```

Observem que nos dois primeiros registros, os valores '83971465842' + '001' estão em duas linhas diferentes. São justamente estes que preciso identificar. Como fazer a consulta?

Answer (score 16):

```
select CPF, MAT, count(*)
from Tabela
group by CPF, MAT
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Resolveu! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Então aceita a resposta que mais te ajudou conforme indica essa [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png).

Answer (score 7):

```
Select *
From tabela t1
Where       exists (select CPF, MAT
                    from Tabela t2
                    where t2.cpf = t1.cpf
                    and   t2.mat = t1.mat
                    group by CPF, MAT 
                    having count(*) > 1)
```

Expandindo um pouco a resposta acima listando todos os registros da tabela duplicada, a passo seguinte , creio , seria alguma ação nos duplicados, deletar ou alterar, esta query é base para isto.

Refiz a query pois a sintaxe pensada não funcionou no Sql Server

Comment: Ocorreu esse erro...
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: Refiz a query , a anterior funciona no Oracle, em SqlServer deve ser diferente, esta deve funcionar.

Comment: Resolveu!!! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -4):

A titulo de conhecimento dos senhores, eu fiz um select onde na minha tabela eu tenho nomes diferentes com CPF iguais.

EX: ARTUR LIRA
CPF: 024.309.258.23

ARTUR LIRA FILHO
CPF: 024.309.258.23

SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(trim(nome)::varchar), '' >>> '') AS nomes, translate(cpf,''./- ()'','''') AS cpf, count (*) AS total FROM tabela_clientes GROUP BY translate(cpf,''./- ()'','''') HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY array_to_string(array_agg(trim(nome)::varchar), '' >>> '');

Eu tenho o seguinte resultado.

nomes cpf total
ARTUR LIRA >>> ARTUR LIRA FILHO 024.309.258.23 2

Não sei seria pertinente neste caso mas pode resolver o problema e sanar duvidas de muitos, meu banco de dados é PostgreSql.